# Apply pixel shader effect to WebBrowser control?

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control, shader

`Effect`'s do not seem to work on the `WebBrowser` control in WPF (.NET 4.0), I'm assuming due to a limitation. Is there any work around to this limitation, or an alternative control for rendering/interop'ing with a web document while still being able to apply WPF shader effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update this Q&A -- I've come across [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/) which has a WPF wrapper, and I was able to succesfully apply pixel shader effects to it (very cool). The only part that doesn't quite work are the plugins (Flash, Google Earth, etc), but otherwise it seems like a nice solution.